# Please help break down this sentence: "bespoke development software co-ordination of departmental..."

Tags: sentence-construction, parsing

I've tried to parse this [sentence](https://demo.plainlanguage.gov/resources/articles/complex-abstract-words/) out many times and still could not find where are the main clause and its verb. I am writing to ask for help to break it down.

> bespoke development software co-ordination of departmental output
> customer relationship management enterprise resource planning live
> operation management mentoring relationship network-centric
> enterprises object relational technology ongoing contractual
> relationships overall control environment proactive system-based
> solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a sentence. It doesn't even try to be (note that it doesn't start with a capital letter).  It is presented as an example of how using lots of complex words makes a phrase harder to understand.  I think it is just a list of phrases, all run together "bespoke  development software" and "co-ordination of departmental output" and "customer relationship management" and ...

Don't try to parse it.  Just observe that it can't be understood, and learn why you should try to use simple clear English.